# What is “Ensemble of 5 reversed LSTMs” in seq2seq

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, seq2seq

While reading the seq2seq [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215) (Sutskever, I., Vinyals, O., & Le, Q. V. (2014). Sequence to sequence learning with neural networks. Advances in neural information processing systems, 27.), the authors said they used a 4-layer LSTMs in *section 3.4 Training Details*<sup>1</sup>. However, in *section 3.6 Experimental Results*<sup>2</sup>, they said they used an ensemble of 5 reversed LSTMs.

I'm pretty consfused about this, since I think *an ensemble of 5 reversed LSTMs* menas a 5-layer LSTMs, which conflicts with the section 3.4. I don't know whether this is a typo or I misundertand the meaning of the 5 reversed LSTMs.

[1]:

> We used deep LSTMs with **4 layers**,
> with 1000 cells at each layer and 1000 dimensional word embeddings, with an input vocabulary
> of 160,000 and an output vocabulary of 80,000.

[2]:
[image]

I have Googled：

- "5 reversed LSTMs" meaning
- "ensemble 5 reversed LSTMs" meaning
- "Ensemble of 5 reversed LSTMs" 4 layers

and found nothing help, and the repos in Github don't have the relevant issues/questions.